# Java GUI getting hanged before networking

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, networking, event-dispatch-thread

I am developing a game in Java.
In the server side,at one place i change the gui before sending the info to the clients.
When i run it without the networking part(Tag 1 in the code),it runs good.But when i do networking part(take note it is done after the gui part and i've encoded a 5 sec sleep thread part too),gui hangs.

Here is a short snippet of our code:

```
public void startgame()
{
    Main.setx=Start.setx;
    Main.sety=Start.sety;
    gui1 = new Main(); //  Bind it
    gui1.setOpaque(true);
    container.add(gui1);
    container.remove(hostpanel);
    container.setSize(Start.setx,Start.sety);
    container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Start.setx,Start.sety));
    container.setVisible(true);
    container.repaint();
    gui=(Main)gui1;                   // 1
try {
        System.out.println("Thread sleeping");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Thread awake");
    if(vector.get(0)!=null)
    {
        pl1=new Human_player(vector.get(0));
        pl1.send(1);
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if(vector.get(1)!=null)
    {
        pl2=new Human_player(vector.get(1));
        pl2.send(2);
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if(vector.get(2)!=null)
    {
        pl3=new Human_player(vector.get(2));
        pl3.send(3);
    }
    else
    {

    }
    ArrayList<Integer> cards=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=51;i++)
    {
        cards.add(i,i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(cards);
    table=new Table(cards.get(0),cards.get(1),cards.get(2),cards.get(3),4);
    Vector<Integer> temp=new Vector<Integer>();
    for(i=4;i<16;i++)
    {
        temp.add(cards.get(i));
    }
    pl1.set_cards(temp);
    if(pl1.type=="human")
    {
        pl1.send(temp);
        pl1.send(table.heaps.get(0).get(0));
        pl1.send(table.heaps.get(1).get(0));
        pl1.send(table.heaps.get(2).get(0));
        pl1.send(table.heaps.get(3).get(0));
    }
    temp.clear();
    for(i=16;i<28;i++)
    {
        temp.add(cards.get(i));
    }
    pl2.set_cards(temp);
    if(pl2.type=="human")
    {   
        pl2.send(temp);
        pl2.send(table.heaps.get(0).get(0));
        pl2.send(table.heaps.get(1).get(0));
        pl2.send(table.heaps.get(2).get(0));
        pl2.send(table.heaps.get(3).get(0));
    }
    System.out.println("Making Initial arrangements");
    temp.clear();
    for(i=28;i<40;i++)
    {
        temp.add(cards.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println("Making Initial arrangements");
    pl3.set_cards(temp);
    if(pl3.type=="human")
    {
        System.out.println("Making Initial arrangements");
        pl3.send(temp);
        pl3.send(table.heaps.get(0).get(0));
        pl3.send(table.heaps.get(1).get(0));
        pl3.send(table.heaps.get(2).get(0));
        pl3.send(table.heaps.get(3).get(0));
        System.out.println("Initial arrangement made");
    }
    for(i=40;i<52;i++)
    {
        mycards.add(cards.get(i));
    }
    playgame();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

GUIs hang when you sleep or engage in blocking operations on the event thread. So don't do that. Use separate threads.

Comment: One way to shift long running operations to another thread is to use a `SwingWorker`. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Actually the title of the question is quite misleading.Here,as the code shows the previous panel is removed and a new one is attached before the networking part or blocking operations come into play.So the gui must've changed before hanging up,,but it doesn't change.

However if i run the code upto tag 1 (excluding all networking part(which is by the way after the gui change code)) it works swiftly.CAN't understand this behaviour

Comment: @nav Well it's your title. It's up to you to make your question clear. At the moment you're just adding to the confusion. I suggest you edit it thoroughly, both title and body, to reflect what you are actually asking, or delete it and try again.